# How do I know if a website accepts iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, http, iframe, http-headers

I'm looking for a way to check if a website accepts iframes (through `X-Frame-options` maybe?) but I can't even read that on client-side.

How can I check if a website allow it on client-side?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a header from the url with the option "`X-Frame-Options`".
This will return `DENY`, `SAMEORIGIN` or `ALLOW-FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this if you are attempting to load a url in your iframe from another domain.

```
//get the iframe object
var iframe = document.getElementById('Frame');


var iframeDocument;


    try{

        //cross browser solution to get the iframe document
        //of the iframe
        iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

    }
    catch(error){

        alert(error);

    }
```

Comment: i got an error even if the iframe is correctly loaded

Comment: @nootb What error are you getting? It is working for me. What is the id of your frame? I used Frame for my example but you will have to change the document.getElementById() parameter to match the id of your iframe.

Comment: @noob I apologize, somehow when I selected the  iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document; part to copy and paste into the solution it switched the scrabbled some letters in the Document part. I corrected the syntax error. Try it again when you get the chance and let me know if it works for you.